# Retrieve data in Select Option in Edit Page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4. I'm having some problem. I have a users table with fields like. State, Region, Area and City, they are all in string (varchar).

Now, I have my "Edit Users" page. In edit users how can I display the users info ing State, Region etc. in a Select Dropdown? Here's my code.

```
{{ Form::select('state', array(
'' => 'Choose One', 1 => 'Luzon', 2 => 'Visayas', 3 => 'Mindanao'), 
null,
array('class' => 'selectpicker', 
'id' => 'state', 
'data-live-search' => 'true',
'onchange' => 'document.getElementById("state2").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text'
 ));
  }}
```

How can I make a value for that specific user already appeared or selected in the dropdown?
Thanks!

Comment: what value do you want default ?

Comment: The Value must be from the table users. That Page is for Edit Users. So I have existing Users with info about him and I just want to show that info in the dropdown list.

Comment: still doesn't clarify ... how do you know what you want to be the default item in the select ?

Comment: The default value in the list depends on the User that you want to edit. Example: username: Yassi, state: Luzon, region: Region I. Now in the dropdown list when I edit Yassi, the state dropdown list should have "Luzon" as default value selected.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
$states = array( 'Choose One', 'Luzon', 'Visayas', 'Mindanao' );

{{ Form::select('state', 
    $states, 
    array_search($user->State, $states ),  // default value
    array(
        'class' => 'selectpicker', 
        'id' => 'state', 
        'data-live-search' => 'true',
        'onchange' => 'document.getElementById("state2").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text'
    ));  
}}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Here's my Table Structure.
id ->int
state-> varchar
region-> varchar
area-> varchar

Now, If I try to make it Auth::user()->state_id it wont work because    in my table state is varchar not an int or id.

Comment: well obviously change the field names